# Getting 403 Forbidden while ajax search functionality in user module Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

In my application Drupal base functionality,
When I press the "search" button on the user list page, it's showing a popup with a 403 Forbidden error.

Getting 403 Forbidden while ajax search functionality in user module Drupal 7

[View error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIel6.png)

In my application Drupal base functionality,
When I press the "search" button on the user list page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can see the real problem in the log messages (using dblog: **/admin/reports/dblog**) or catch the server log.

On the log you can see the real reason of this error.